# Save a region of screen in WPF app following MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a WPF application following the MVVM architecture.

**On one of the screens is a chart which needs to be saved as an image file on Save button click.**

I can save the chart using the below code in **code behind**:

```
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, bmp.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        bmp.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

But I need to be able to do this in my ViewModel.

For this purpose, I pass the ActualHeight & ActualWidth as the command parameters for the Click command of the button in below manner:

```
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding MyViewModel.SaveCommand">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DimensionConverter}">
             <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="MyChart"/>
             <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="MyChart"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

In my converter:

```
public class DimensionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, ...)
    {
        return values.Clone();
    }

    ...
}
```

Then, in command execution logic:

```
public void OnExecute(object parameter)
{
    var values = (object[])parameter;
    var width = (double)values[0];
    var height = (double)values[1];
    ...
}
```

But, I also need to be able to pass the co-ordinates of the Chart control wrt Origin. This can be done using [PointToScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen(v=vs.110).aspx) method. **But how can I pass them to the view model keeping in mind MVVM?**

Or is there any other way that I can capture a region of a screen & save as image in MVVM architecture?

Comment: As a possible way to implement this is to  use Messanger pattern(for example Messager in MVVM Light framework) and send a command from your View to ViewModel with a bitmap to  save. That will still keep your app in MVVM way.

Comment: @VitaliyK: Could you point me to a link or reference where I can get more information from?

Comment: https://mallibone.com/post/mvvmlight-messenger  - as an example

Comment: This is similar to Commands itself. How can I pass a bitmap using this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is there any other way that I can capture a region of a screen & save as image in MVVM architecture?

The view could implement an interface that declares properties for all information the view model needs to know about:

```
public interface IView
{
    double Width { get; }
    double Height { get; }
    double X { get; }
    double Y { get; }
}
```

You could then pass the view itself as a parameter to the command of the view model:

```
Command = new DelegateCommand<IView>(view => { /* do something */});
```

This doesn't break the MVVM pattern since the view model has no *direct* reference to the view. It only knows about an interface that the view happens to implement.

The interface may even declare methods. In some scenarios only the view, or a control in the view, may know how to for example serialize itself and then you have to delegate this functionality to the view because the view model cannot be supposed to know how to actually serialize a control. This is an implementation detail of control itself.

The view model still has to initiate the serialization process though which means that it has to be able to communicate with the view one way or another. Using an interface is one way to do this. Another way is to use a messenger or an event aggregator. Please refer to the following blog post if you want to learn the concept: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/.

Comment: The DelegateCommand here means it is implementing the ICommand interface, right?

Comment: Yes, DelegateCommand is Prism's implementation of the ICommand interface: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Commands/DelegateCommand.cs

Comment: I have one more clarification, how can I pass view as the parameter to the command of the view model?

Comment: By binding the CommandParameter to the view itself: <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}"/>. Change Window to UserControl if the view is a UserControl. Please remember to accept the answer and vote it up if helps you.

Comment: How could this be unit tested? Since the interface is implemented in code behind & the command logic in the view model?

Comment: You typically don't unit test the views or any view related functionality. The view model can easily be unit tested by simply providing it with a mock implementation of the interface. But please ask a new question if you have another issue.